How to set maximum shipping cost with Woocommerce flat rate shipping?
How can I set a max_fee for flat fee shipping costs in WooCommerce?
Right now I have the base shipping at $4 + (0.5 * qty) but I want to make the shipping $6 maximum. From what I see online, the only way to use the min and max_fee parameters is if you use percentage based shipping calculations.
I just want the shipping cost to increase .50 for each additional cart quantity until it reaches $6, then it stays at $6 after any additional quantity more.

We expect you to better search and provide in your question your code attempt with details and explanations… Please, note that stack overflow is not a free coding service. As a starting base, making some changes to this answer code will allow you to set a max cost for your flat rates shipping methods... The correct hook to be used is woocommerce_package_rates filter hook like in those related threads...
